# How to grab data that is not in html source but visible from browser?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsoup, data-extraction

The data I want is visible from the browser, but I can't find it from the html source code. I suspect the data was generated by scripts. I'd like to grad such kind of data. Is it possible using Jsoup? I'm aware Jsoup just does not execute Javascript.

Take [this page](http://nd.edu/) for example, I'd like to grab all the colleges and schools under Academics -> COLLEGES & SCHOOLS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dom content is generated via scripts or plugins, then you really should consider a scriptable browser like [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/). Then you can just write some javascript to extract the data.

I didn't check your link, and I assume you're looking for a general answer not specific to any page.